# An attribute error appeared when I tried to make a code allowing a user to create their own record

Tags: python, arrays, list, record

I am trying to allow a user to create their own record and output their record. When I run my code this message appears:

File "filename", line 25, in 
record = user_class(fact_list)
File "filename", line 17, in **init**
self.feild_list[i]=feild_list[i]
AttributeError: 'user_class' object has no attribute 'feild_list'

This is my code:

```
user_list = []

choice=input("Enter choice (Y/N):")

if choice == "Y":
    feild_list = []

    record_length = int(input("Enter record length:"))

    for i in range(record_length):
        feild = input("Enter a feild:")
        feild_list.append(feild)

    class user_class():
        def __init__(self, feild_list):
            for i in range(record_length):
                self.feild_list[i]=feild_list[i]

    fact_list = []

    for i in range(len(feild_list)):
        fact = input("Enter a fact:")
        fact_list.append(fact)
    
    record = user_class(fact_list)

    user_list.append(record)
    print(user_list)

    choice=input("Enter choice (Y/N):") 
        
elif choice == "N":
    print("Program Ended.")

else:
    while choice != "Y" or choice != "N":
        print("Invalid choice")
        choice = input("Enter choice (Y/N):")
```

Comment: Replace `self.feild_list` with `feild_list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `user_class.__init__()` you don't have a `self.feild_list` variable.  I assume you want one (see below).  Alternatively you could just clone the list `self.feild_list = feild_list[:]`.

```
user_list = []

choice = input("Enter choice (Y/N):")

if choice == "Y":
    feild_list = []

    record_length = int(input("Enter record length:"))

    for i in range(record_length):
        feild = input("Enter a feild:")
        feild_list.append(feild)

    class user_class():
        def __init__(self, feild_list):
            self.feild_list = []
            for i in range(record_length):
                self.feild_list.append(feild_list[i])

    fact_list = []

    for i in range(len(feild_list)):
        fact = input("Enter a fact:")
        fact_list.append(fact)

    record = user_class(fact_list)

    user_list.append(record)
    print(user_list)

    choice = input("Enter choice (Y/N):")
elif choice == "N":
    print("Program Ended.")

else:
    while choice != "Y" and choice != "N":
        print("Invalid choice")
        choice = input("Enter choice (Y/N):")
```

Also fixed the logic error in the choice retry.  Consider moving that retry logic to the start so always get a valid choice:

```
while True:
    choice = input("Enter choice (Y/N):")
    if choice in "NY":
        break
    print("Invalid choice")
```

Comment: Thanks for help. However, when I run the code. The list appears as this: [<__main__.user_class object at 0x10dfc3850>]

Comment: @NathanielBassey Yes, I know, and that's because you do `print(user_list)`.  If you need help with customizing your class to pretty print a string please open another issue.

Comment: I have created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75303138/how-to-customise-a-class-to-print-a-string